# How to convert a MonoMac project to Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, mono, monomac, xamarin.mac

We have an existing MonoMac project that we have not updated lately. We just tried to make some updates and compile a release and we got an error stating "Bundling the Mono Runtime is only supported in Xamarin.Mac". We used to be able to include the Mono runtime in the application bundle, but I guess this was disabled once Xamarin.Mac was released.

So, we purchased Xamarin.Mac. Now, how do we convert our MonoMac project to a Xamarin.Mac project?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: fwiw, you can click the checkbox to accept your own answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A separate installation needs to be run to install the Xamarin.Mac package. Once that is done when you try to open a MonoMac project in Xamarin Studio you will get a button asking if you would like to migrate the code to Xamarin.Mac.

To get this download, sign in with your account on the Xamarin website, then in your account click on the Downloads link and you will see the OS X download for Xamarin.Mac.